# It is/was not like we needed more food. - is or was

Tags: tense

**Example 1**

> It **is** not like we needed more food.

**Example 2**

> It **was** not like we needed more food.

When the clause after "not like" is past tense, what tense do we use, is or was?

Answer (score 2):

Either one is fine, but I would definitely expect the present more often — even though it would seem to make less sense.<sup>1</sup>

Note that since this expression is very informal, it only sounds natural with a contraction:

> It's not like we needed more food.

> It wasn't like we needed more food.

> It's not like I actually wanted to go.

> It wasn't like a bear was going to eat you.

As [Ed Sheeran sang](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c0-OcrRSCbs):

> It's not like we were both on tour.<sup>2</sup>

As [an alleged murderer told police](https://www.therecord.com/news/waterloo-region/2016/02/18/it-wasn-t-like-we-were-dating-or-anything-ball-told-police.html):

> It wasn't like we were dating or anything.

These examples took two minutes to search up; you can easily find many more to verify that both tenses are commonly used with this expression, even for past events.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> One wonders whether the "like" in this expression is etymologically the one in "likely", i.e. "coherent with the facts", in which case the tenselessness is easier to understand.</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup> Interestingly, this one carries a note of irony (they *were* on tour), whereas the next one is a straight denial.</sub>

Comment: You are right that it only sounds correct with a contraction. Remember that ***It's*** can be read as ***It was***. That may be why "It's not like we needed more food" sounds idiomatic, while "It is not that we needed more food" doesn't. But I'd still prefer "It was..."

Answer (score 0):

That depends whether the event you are describing is past or present. If it's present, I'd say, "It is not like we need more food." If it's past, "It was not like we needed more food."

Answer (score -1):

It's a (rather unusual) hypothetical present statement: we don't need more at the moment. Because it's hypothetical, we are describing the situation now, so we use the present tense of **is**, but we [backshift](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/english-grammar-reference/wishes-and-hypotheses) the tense of the bit that's hypothetical- **needed**.

> It's not like we needed more food.